# Cocoapods pod install as a target dependency

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I've created an external build system target in my Xcode project and made it a dependency of the main target, so I want this target run before the main target starts building. In this external build system target I simply reference a bash script to run `pod install` from the SRCROOT dir.

As expected, my new target runs first and `Pod install` runs fine but then the build stops. It does not fail however, it just reports the Build stopped with no issues. The exit code from pod install is 0 so the script should return as successful yet the build stops.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: What build system are you using? And are you making sure to compile the `.xcworkspace` instead of your normal `.xcodeproj`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to implement the same functionality directly in CocoaPods and experienced the same behavior. I think that Xcode aborts the build as CocoaPods performs changes in the Pods project, which is recreated from scratch at the moment.

This approach might be viable once we start to edit in place the Pods project in CocoaPods.

Comment: Good to know you saw the same issue. I thought I was going crazy. Any idea what Cocoapods version this may be included in? Thanks for your response.