# Build stopped without previous errors

Tags: xcode

In Xcode 11 beta 4, the app compiles and copies, but then it tells `Build stopped ... no issues`. The app does not start then.

What reasons may cause this behaviour?
[image]

Comment: Well... no. Just press CMD-R to run the app, wait, and see it stopping.

Comment: Not on my machine. That is what I'm telling you. I don't know what's interrupting the build but I'm suggesting it is being interrupted.

Comment: Are you using any pods? I see duplicate answers that talk about those being the problem.

Comment: No pods, no carthage, no packages. This seems very strange to me, please see also my comment further down that page.

Comment: The same happens to me with Xcode 15 beta. No pods, no frameworks, no Command-Period. It just stops.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this by hitting Command-Period in the middle of a build.

[image]

In other words, I'm suggesting that "stopped" here doesn't mean "came to a stop", but rather "was stopped" - i.e., "you stopped me." That's the only thing I can think of - you're interrupting the build somehow.

I also see duplicate answers suggesting that a pod script can cause this:

[Cocoapods pod install as a target dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946022/cocoapods-pod-install-as-a-target-dependency)

Comment: Well, if so, then by telepathy... Using Xcode plain, by the way, no pods, no swift packages, no carthage. But I have several self-created frameworks in the workspace, but those of them the main app uses (currently just two) build separately without any problems.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are thinking "stop" in your mind and the build stops. Try to relax more! :)

Comment: More seriously, maybe the frameworks are a clue. What if you duplicate your project but take out the frameworks. Does that build? If so you've found the source of the problem, even if not the problem itself.

Comment: Actually, I thought "stop stopping", but it already reacts on the first of both words... Will try to approach the framework question...

Comment: So, created new workspace, new project, no frameworks, recreated code, building for Mac => Same unmotivated stop.

Comment: This is interesting (I have another question open for that): The build log has no errors, but two of these warnings: ```
Showing Recent Messages
Directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/undefined'
```

Comment: In that question you say "When building my project for iOS only, everything's fine. When adding the "Mac" option, there is a strange error". How is the same app going to build for iOS and Mac? Is this one of those newfangled Catalyst thingies?

Answer (score -1):

You can try cleaning project use this command : `cmd + k`

and then rebuild your project .

hope it helps

Comment: I already tried all "classic" methods to get behind this problem, and searched the internet, but nothing helps. No "clean derived data", no project clean, nothing. Possibly, it has something to do with the new catalyst feature; I believe this behaviour appeared after checking the "Mac" option in the project settings, and it does not disappear when unchecking that option.